# CSS is not used by template

Tags: templates, go

I'm using a template that links to a CSS file, and following some other posts on this board, I think I have everything correct, but the CSS is still not being applied.  Also, when I use the Developer tools in Chrome is see the link to the CSS file as I put in in the template, and if I click on it, it takes me to the CSS file, which I assume shows me it can find the file.

Go code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "os"
    "text/template"
    "net/http"
)

var tpl *template.Template

func init() {
    tpl = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("templates/*"))
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    host, _ := os.Hostname()
    err := tpl.Execute(w, host)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Template Execute failed: ", err)
    }
}

func process(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r.ParseForm()
    fmt.Println(r.Form)
    fmt.Println("path", r.URL.Path)
    fmt.Println("scheme", r.URL.Scheme)
    fmt.Println(r.Form["url_long"])
    for k, v := range r.Form {
        fmt.Println("key:", k)
        fmt.Println("val:", strings.Join(v, ""))
    }
    fmt.Println(r.Form["wall"])
}

func main() {
    host, _ := os.Hostname()
    fmt.Println("host =", host)
    //err = tpl.Execute(f, host)

    swall := http.NewServeMux()
    //fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("www"))
    //swall.Handle("/", fs)
    swall.Handle("/resources/", http.StripPrefix("/resources/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("resources"))))
    swall.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    swall.HandleFunc("/process", process)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", swall)
}
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Great Wall</title>
    <link href="/resources/css/gwall.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <div id="page_title">
            <h1>Great Wall</h1>
        </div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
    color: red;
    font-size: 36pt;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I tried everything I can think of and searched for several days, but I don't have much experience with templates and I'm at a complete loss right now. I know when someone tells me what I'm doing wrong I'll end up smacking myself on the forehead, but at this point I'll risk the bruising.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: try <link href="/resources/css/gwall.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: Hi, the issue might be in the way the mux is routing your requests. Try and remove the root handler, using instead another URI than "/" like `swall.HandleFunc("/app", handler)` or removing the trailing slash from resources like `swall.Handle("/resources", http.FileServer(http.Dir("resources"))`

Comment: @FrancescoGualazzi He wrote that the http-server is delivering the file. What MIME-Type is the server serving? you can check in the chrome-dev network tab.

Comment: Took out the type="text/css" as it was causing an error.

Comment: @user2592525 So like i guessed its a MIME-Type issue. Try to solve that rather then removing the type.

Comment: @FrancescoGualazzi I tried your suggestions but no joy.

Comment: Thanks you, Tiega!  That fixed it!  I can live with a warning/

Comment: You're missing rel="stylesheet"